# How do I use DownloadListener in Android WebView fragment?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, android-download-manager

I am trying to make an Android WebView App. It contains three WebView in three fragments. It's working but I cannot download anything from URL which are available in the webpage.

This is my HomeFragment.java code

```
package com.assamese.web.myapplicationtest.ui.gallery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.assamese.web.myapplicationtest.R;
import com.assamese.web.myapplicationtest.WebViewController;

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
galleryViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
WebView webView = root.findViewById(R.id.web_view_dictionary);
webView.loadUrl("URL");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());
return root;
 }
}
```

and WebViewController.java code

```
package com.assamese.web.myapplicationtest;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

// class is extended to WebViewClient to access the WebView
public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

// loadurl function will load the
// url we will provide to our webview
view.loadUrl(url);
return true;
}
}
```

and fragment_home.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <!--WebView is added on full screen so
        that application interface can be
        interactive and user can the web content
        is visible on full screen -->
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view_asomiablog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I also add MainActivity.java code

```
package com.assamese.web.myapplicationtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
          .setAction("Action", null).show();
      }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
        R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
      .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
      .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration) ||
      super.onSupportNavigateUp();
  }
}
```

Please tell me in detail how I can implement DownloadListener code into the 'HomeFragment.java' to download any file from URL(of webpage) within the WebView app. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318347/how-to-download-a-file-in-app-with-webview-component) but I failed. I am new in this world. Please..

Comment: I am really sorry. I never thought about it. Now I edited the post.

Comment: I edited the question, please check .

Comment: Please explain in the beginning of your post how you try to download. Dont let us dig through all that code to find out.